# Destination host is unreachable in LAN

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, routing

I have TP-LINK router which gets internet from fiber optic. Router is connected to Server(Microsoft Windows Server 2008R2). My server has 2 Ethernet Card, first one is getting internet(WAN) from router. Second one is distributing internet to other computers(LAN). I am using routing and remote control from Administrator of Windows Server R2 to distribute internet. Internet is working fine in all PC. But what I want, is to use one of LAN user's printer. User PC has IP of 192.168.1.85. My server IP is 192.168.1.2. Router IP is 192.168.1.1. When I ping 192.168.1.85 the host is unreachable. When I ping 192.168.1.1, it is ok. All PC are in WORKGROUP. What can be the problem. Please show me direction. 
Thanks in advance.

EDIT
ipconfig /all 
Windows IP Configuration

```
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : KURBONOV1
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8057 PCI-E Gigabit Ether
net Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1D-BA-EF-47-7B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-22-FB-69-27-E6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.123(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 91.200.216.2
                                       91.200.216.7
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 6:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 7:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-00-54-55-4E-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:2046:2217:3f57:fe84(Pref
erred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2046:2217:3f57:fe84%12(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{CA5BAAC0-79D3-4DBA-838D-481359920
C71}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 13:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 20:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{C1121A84-3E64-4076-93C4-3FECC1337
64B}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 21:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 22:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 23:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 24:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 26:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 27:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 28:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 30:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 31:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 32:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 33:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 34:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 35:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 36:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF400
1E2}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 38:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

route print

```
Interface List
 10 ...00 1d ba ef 47 7b ...... Marvell Yukon 88E8057 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Con
troller
 11 ...00 22 fb 69 27 e6 ...... Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN
  1 ........................... Software Loopback Interface 1
 20 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 12 ...02 00 54 55 4e 01 ...... Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 31 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{CA5BAAC0-79D3-4DBA-838D-481359920C71}
 24 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 29 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{C1121A84-3E64-4076-93C4-3FECC133764B}
 25 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  6TO4 Adapter
 26 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 27 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 28 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 32 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 18 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 33 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 35 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 36 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 37 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 38 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 39 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 40 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 41 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{1C73FE11-C907-4519-B95C-B17DCF4001E2}
 42 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  6TO4 Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.123    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.123    281
    192.168.1.123  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.123    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.123    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.123    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.123    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 12     38 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 12     38 2001::/32                On-link
 12    286 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:2046:2217:3f57:fe84/128
                                    On-link
 12    286 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    286 fe80::2046:2217:3f57:fe84/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    286 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Disable the firewall on the client PC to see if that's the problem.

Comment: I have tried this as well, did not help.

Comment: Then something else is blocking the ICMP traffic.. :)

Comment: I think problem is related with TP Link router or Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Please post the output of `ipconfig /all` and `route print`

Comment: see my edited question

Comment: I don't think it's the router (you're in the same subnet), and Win2008R2 (you can ping another client). It's 99% the client in my opinion

Comment: I can not ping even from Win2008R2, that is why I think it is something related with server configuration.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov I'm assuming the network card that is connected to the TPLink is either picking up a public IP by DHCP from your provider or it has a statically assigned public IP.  If that's the case it may be trying to send the ping requests out the wrong network card/interface.  Try pinging google.com and see if you get a response.

Comment: I would check the client computer. You might have the gateway set to 192.168.1.1 in which case it would work but be bypassing your RRAS server for internet access. Also, just a suggestion, but if you have a server running RRAS you should place your internal network on a different subnet. If only for clarity.

Comment: @BradBouchard Yes it has statically assigned IP(Public Ip provided by ISP). google.com response for ping. How can I solve this issue. Please show me direction.

Comment: @ByronC. Yes you are right. Clients gateway is set to 192.168.1.1  If I place internal network to other subnet will it work?

Comment: Don't place the internal network to the other gateway, that would be bad.  See my answer...

Comment: I'm not clear on your topology. Are both NICs on the RRAS server connected to the router or is the RRAS server physically between your router and the LAN? It sounds like all your systems are physically plugged into the router (in which case I'm not sure why you are setting up a RRAS server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of the rest of the story that I've got out of you through comments, you will want to add a static route on the server for the 192.168.1.0/24 LAN network that your 2nd adapter is on.  This route will tell traffic destined for 192.168.1.0/24 hosts to use the "LAN" adapter and leave the Internet (public IP assigned adapter) to the other adapter.  You can open Command Prompt to add routes.

Your route will look something like:  route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
(This is just an example to get as close to your environment as I can, but read the guide linked below for a better understanding.  You will more than likely have to tweak your IPs used for these route(s) based on your internal gateway.)

[Here is a simple guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/) for setting up, and understanding, static routes.